# Book recommendations for linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, reference-request, vector-spaces, book-recommendation

I have been wanting to learn about linear algebra (specifically about vector spaces) for a long time, but I am not sure what book to buy, any suggestions?

Comment: Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* is a good text on linear mappings and vector spaces without being bogged down by determinants (banished to the end of the text).

Comment: Are you looking for a vector-space-theory-oriented linear algebra or a matrx-theory-oriented linear algebra text? Recommendations could depend on this. :)

Comment: I am looking more for vector space theory

Comment: Voting to reopen because this question is about vector space theory, while the alleged dupe target is clearly application-focused.

Answer (score 23):

Some free sources well worth their salt (more so, I think, than many existing books):

- [Jim Hefferon, *Linear Algebra*](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/). This is a well-known open-source textbook and has lots of good exercises.
- [Isaiah Lankham, Bruno Nachtergaele, Anne Schilling, *Linear Algebra - As an Introduction to Abstract Mathematics*](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Eanne/linear_algebra/). This one is less comprehensive and detailed as some might like, but it's good at what it does.

Here are some others that I haven't taken a proper look at, but suspect to be of high quality as well:

- [Peter J. Cameron, *Notes on Linear Algebra*](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/%7Epjc/notes/linalg.pdf). I haven't actually checked this one out, but I know Cameron as a good writer.
- [Sergei Treil, *Linear Algebra Done Wrong*](https://sites.google.com/a/brown.edu/sergei-treil-homepage/linear-algebra-done-wrong). This one has somewhat of a geometric slant and assumes more familiarity with mathematics than the others.
- [William Chen, *Linear Algebra*](https://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/lnlafolder/lnla.html).

All of the above cover vector spaces. As far as linear algebra without abstract vector spaces (i.e., "matrix algebra") is concerned, I can highly recommend the following:

- [Neil Strickland, *Linear Mathematics with Applications*](https://neilstrickland.github.io/linear_maths/). These notes are much more rigorous than the title might make you believe.

Answer (score 11):

A standard book for a first course in linear algebra is Gilbert Strang's [Linear Algebra and Its Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0030105676). After getting an initial exposure, Sheldon Axler's [Linear Algebra Done Right](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387982582) is a good book for getting a more abstract view of linear algebra (at Carnegie Mellon, this is used for a second course in linear algebra). Finally, if you want a very abstract view of linear algebra in relation to other algebraic structures such as fields and modules, you can read the relevant portions of the legendary [Abstract Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471433349) by Dummit and Foote.

Comment: Sergei Treil's [Linear Algebra Done Wrong](https://www.math.brown.edu/~treil/papers/LADW/book.pdf) is also nice

Answer (score 3):

I think linear algebra by Hoffman and Kunze and linear algebra by Serge Lang are great books.

Also, MIT ocw has a very good online linear algebra course (including assignments, but you would need Strang's book for doing those):

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/index.htm

Comment: Serge Lang's book is terse but very widely used.

Answer (score 3):

Differential Equations and Linear Algebra (Third Edition) by Stephen W. Goode and Scott A. Annin is a good textbook, as is Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote, and Linear Algebra by Stephen H. Friedberg, Arnold J. Insel, and Lawrence E. Spence.