# How to consider F to check if set V qualifies as a vector space or not if no information of field F is given?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

A set *V* qualifies to be a vector space if it satisfies properties under addition and scalar multiplication over a field *F*. Let's say if a set *V* is given but the field *F* is not specified and it is given to check if set *V* is a vector space or not. Shall I consider *F* as both R (set of real numbers) and C (set of complex numbers) to check if
*V* is a vector space or not OR anyone is sufficient??

Comment: Do you assume you know the addition structure on $V$? (btw, any $\mathbb C$-vector space is automatically also an $\mathbb R$-vector space.)

Comment: @KentaS yes addition structure is known.

Comment: @KentaS I am new to Linear Algebra course. Can you suggest few books or video lectures that would be help me in developing basics concepts !!

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while since I studied linear algebra, so I'm not super sure. Lax's *Linear Algebra and Its Applications* and Lang's *Algebra* are canonical references, though. Also try checking out this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377980/book-recommendations-for-linear-algebra

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to interpret the question as being:

> Let $V$ be an abelian group. When does there exist a field $F$ and an $F$-action on $V$ (i.e., scalar multiplication) which makes $V$ an $F$-vector space?

The first observation is that *any* field $F$ is an extension of $\mathbb Q$ or a finite field $\mathbb F_p$, depending on the characteristic. Thus, it suffices to consider whether $V$ is a $\mathbb Q$-vector space or a $\mathbb F_p$-vector space.

I claim $V$ can be made an $\mathbb F_p$-vector space iff $V$ is $p$-torsion. (i.e., for any $v\in V$, we have $pv=0$.)

$\Rightarrow$: $pv:=v+\dots+v\ (p\text{ times})=(1+\dots+1)v=0v=0$.

$\Leftarrow$: Any element $a\in\mathbb F_p\cong\mathbb Z/p$ lifts to a positive integer $\tilde a>0\in\mathbb Z$. Let $a\cdot v:=\tilde a\cdot v$. This is well-defined since $V$ is $p$-torsion. (Note that $\tilde a\cdot v$ simply means $v+\dots+v$, adding together $\tilde a$ times.) It is easily checked that this actually does make $V$ an $\mathbb F_p$-vector space.

Next, I claim $V$ can be made a $\mathbb Q$-vector space iff $V$ is uniquely divisible (i.e., for any $v\in V$ and nonzero integer $n$, there exists a unique $w\in V$ such that $v=nw$).

$\Rightarrow$: trivial.

$\Leftarrow$: For each $p/q\in\mathbb Q$ and $v\in V$, let $w\in V$ be such that $v=qw$. Now, we define $p/q\cdot v:=pw$. Again, it is easy to check that this action is well-defined, and that this makes $V$ a $\mathbb Q$-vector space.

---

To summarize, the answer is:

> $V$ must either be uniquely divisible, or there must exist a prime number $p$ such that $V$ is $p$-torsion.

Comment: Addendum: **don't confuse scalar multiplication $n\cdot v$ with $v+\dots+v\ (n\text{ times})$,** which unfortunately is also denoted $n\cdot v$!

Answer (score 3):

You can’t hope that considering $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ would be sufficient.

For example, consider the finite fields $\mathbb F_p$ or $\mathbb F_p \times \mathbb F_p$ where $p$ is a prime number.

On those « sets » $V$, you can define a scalar multiplication $\mathbb F_p \times V \to V$… just take the multiplication of the field!

But there is no obvious scalar multiplication $\mathbb R \times V \to V$. Hence considering $\mathbb R $ or $\mathbb C$ as « natural » fields for vector spaces can’t be done.

*Note: if you’re doing physics, then vector spaces are in most of the cases used with $\mathbb R $ or $\mathbb C$ fields.*

Comment: I am new to Linear Algebra course. Can you suggest few books or video lectures that would be help me in developing basics concepts, which will cover topics like vector spaces, subspaces etc. !!

Comment: @novice I would recommend Linear Algebra by Serge Lang.