# Linear Algebra with Theory

Tags: reference-request

The books I have seen they only go into to process of solving equations and matrices but they don’t offer theorems behind them.

I have studied Gilbert Strang’s linear algebra not all of it. What I studied from there I did not see any theorems, in case I missed.

Now my linear algebra course in college has theorems. I have notes but I need something to study a bit in detail to make sense of arguments. So I would really appreciate if someone can suggest anything.

Comment: You could try linear algebra done right, but without more details on your experiences, knowledge level, and what you're preparing for, this question is vague.  Why aren't the class materials for your current class enough?

Comment: combine more of book you can gather and compare subjects among them

Comment: Have a look here and to the other linked question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377980/book-recommendations-for-linear-algebra

Comment: @MichaelBurr This is because there are things in proofs like using of set systems and not why me made different operations in transformation(just an example) as an argument. 

Your other question I know about transformations, decomposition, eigenvalues.  Pretty much stuff which would be in basic linear algebra class.

Comment: Halmos "Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces" will either teach you some linear algebra or teach you to be careful what you ask for...

Comment: Personally, I can’t really suggest a book, although I’ve heard Jim Hefferon’s book is quite good, even though I think it might be long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider the wonderful text "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Sheldon Axler
https://linear.axler.net/